# React Link to - provide absolute path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have below code

```
<Link className={classes.btnText}  key= {props.id} 
                to= {"https://s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/download.pdf" } target="_blank" download>Brochure <span> &darr; </span> </Link>
```

The issue is i'm not able to give the absolute path. It is getting updated as

```
localhost:3000/https://s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/download.pdf
```

Can i know how to give complete url

Comment: `Link` is for "pages" in your router, if you want to send the user somewhere else use a regular `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `<a>` tag instead

```
<a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/download.pdf" target="_blank" className={classes.btnText}>
```

Comment: Can the download be done in same window than opening in new tab ?

Comment: @upog Yeah, try to play around with adding `download` parameter to `<a>`.

Like `<a download href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/download.pdf" target="_blank" className={classes.btnText}>`

Comment: yeah i tried but it does not work. but i am able to achieve that from other stack overflow post

Answer (score 1):

That's how the {Link} works :)

Maybe use `<a>` tag instead ?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah because Link builds all the routes from your home/root path which is localhost:3000 in local dev environment. So that's why its appending to that.

use `hyperlink tag <a>` instead